# php round float number

Tags: php

I have read the documentation and have clear idea of round but i didn't find useful information to solve the problem.

The problem is i have float number which is let say 1.09 and i want to display it 2 instead of 1. if we use round function it display 1. Help me solve this problem.

MORE DETAILS...

```
$TotalPaidRemaining=1090;
$monthly_installments=1000;
$MakingNumberOfMonths=$TotalPaidRemaining/$monthly_installments;
echo round($MakingNumberOfMonths, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);// it display 1. i want it display 2..
```

What i want is if the value after decimal point is greater than 0. For example 0.01. I want to consider it as 1.

Hope i am clear at my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function instead.

```
$number = ceil(0.1); // $number will be 1
```

From the documentation :

> Returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ceil() php function instead of round(). It will round up your values. Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php 
Example: 
`ceil(1.09); // return 2`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ceil($yourNumber)`, which will round the number to its next higher integer.

Or you could use `round($yourNumber + 0.499999999999999)`.

Or you could use `floor($yourNumber + 1)`, which rounds the number to its previous highest integer.