# Distance calculation results which I want to display to one decimal place

Tags: php, php-5.6

Here I am doing distance calculation between two latitudes and longitudes. It is working fine. I get results like "7.4055315795109" but I don't want to display so many decimal places. My expected result is "7.4". How can I achieve my expected answer?

My code:

```
 <?php
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) 
{ 
   $theta = $lon1 - $lon2; 
   $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)); 
   $dist = acos($dist); 
   $dist = rad2deg($dist); 
   $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
   $unit = strtoupper($unit);

   if ($unit == "K") 
   {
      return ($miles * 1.609344); 
   } 
   else 
   {
      return $miles;
   }
}

// Kilometres
echo distance('12.91747','77.6220413','12.9577129','77.6764937', "K");
?>
```

Comment: have you read the php manual? look at `round(float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )`  ~ http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php round float number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195516/php-round-float-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish the single digit precision rounding you are seeking the built-in function `round` should help - like this:

```
function distance( $lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit='M' ) { 
   $theta = $lon1 - $lon2; 
   $dist = sin( deg2rad( $lat1 ) ) * sin( deg2rad( $lat2 ) ) +  cos( deg2rad( $lat1 ) ) * cos( deg2rad( $lat2 ) ) * cos( deg2rad( $theta ) ); 
   $dist = acos( $dist ); 
   $dist = rad2deg( $dist ); 
   $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
   $unit = strtoupper( $unit );

   if( $unit == "K" ) {/* round the output and reduce precision to 1 digit */
      return round( ( $miles * 1.609344 ), 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ); 
   } else {
      return round( $miles, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP );
   }
}

echo distance('12.91747','77.6220413','12.9577129','77.6764937', "K");

//outputs 7.4
```