# PHP round number with 2 digits to the nearest float number

Tags: php

How can I round 2 digits number to the nearest number using php, to be clear like the example below

```
1.06 => 1.1
1.03 => 1.1
1.02 => 1.0
```

so if the third number greater or equal to 3 then round to 1.1 and so on

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php round float number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195516/php-round-float-number)

Comment: I want to round if the third number greater than 3

Comment: 1.03 then 1.1 but if 1.02 then 1

Comment: You can't using PHP's native functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mynumber=1.03;
$mynumber_exp=explode(".",$mynumber);

$last_digit=substr("$mynumber", -1);

if ($last_digit >= 3) {
  $rounded_number = "$mynumber_exp[0].1";
  echo "$rounded_number"; // PRINT .1
}
else {
  $rounded_number = "$mynumber_exp[0].0";
  echo "$rounded_number"; // PRINT .0
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this with `$mynumber=1.3;` - it shows `1.1`!

Comment: @NigelRen I'm supposing he will always have 1.xx numbers as he asks for third number

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round()`, but you need to add 0.02 to make it round 0.03 up and anything below is rounded down.

```
function round3( $in )  {
    return round($in+0.02, 1);
}

echo round3(1.06).PHP_EOL;
echo round3(1.03).PHP_EOL;
echo round3(1.02);
```

gives

```
1.1
1.1
1
```